# autofac dependancy injection throwing an exception

Tags: config, autofac, code-injection

In my web config I have

```
<configSections>
    <section name="autofac" type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration" />
</configSections>
```

and then...

```
<autofac>
  <components>
    <component type="xyz.Service.TrainerService, xyz.Service" service="xyz.Service.Contracts.ITrainerService,xyz.Service.Contracts">/component>
  </components>
</autofac>
```

inside my WebApiConfig.cs I have the following 2 lines included...

```
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));
var container = builder.Build();
```

TrainerService is the concreate class and ITrainerService is the relevant interface while xyz.Service and xyz.Service.Contracts are namespaces.

But the above code gives me the "The type 'xyz.Service.TrainerService, xyz.Service' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly" error on following line

```
var container = builder.Build();
```

Can some one please give me a solution to this in order to get autofac dependancy injection working?

Comment: If `xyz.Service.TrainerService` is the type, what is the name of the **assembly** that type is in?

Comment: 'xyz.Service' is the name of the assembly `TrainerService`